# Regular expressions to match protected separated values

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to have a regular expression to match a separated values with some protected values that can contain the separator character.

For instance:

```
"A,B,{C,D,E},F"
```

would give:

- "A"
- "B"
- "{C,D,E}"
- "F"

Please note the protected values can be nested, as follows:

```
"A,B,{C,D,{E,F}},G"
```

would give:

- "A"
- "B"
- "{C,D,{E,F}}"
- "G"

I already coded that feature with a character iteration as follow:

```
sub Parse
{
  my @item;

  my $curly;
  my $string;
  foreach(split //)
  {
    $_ eq "{" and ++$curly;
    $_ eq "}" and --$curly;

    if(!$curly && /[,:]/)
    {
      push @item, $string;
      undef $string;
      next;
    }
    $string .= $_;
  }

  push @item, $string;
  return @item;
}
```

But it would definitively be so much nicer with a regexp.

Comment: Do you have `{{A},{B}}` as input?

Comment: Yes, I can have nested `{}`, for instance `A,B,{D,{E,F},G},H` should give `A` `B` `{D,{E,F},G}` `H`

Comment: Regular expressions cannot handle arbitrary levels of nesting. You have to specify a maximum nesting level, or use a proper parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved from nhahtdh's answer.

```
$_ = "A,B,{C,D,E},F";
while ( m/(\{.*?\}|((?<=^)|(?<=,)).(?=,|$))/g ) {
    print "[$&]\n";
}
```

---

Improved it again. Please look at this one!

```
$_ = "A,B,{C,D,{E,F}},G";
while ( m/(\{.*\}|((?<=^)|(?<=,)).(?=,|$))/g ) {
    print "$&\n";
}
```

It will get:

```
A
B
{C,D,{E,F}}
G
```

Comment: Impressive regexp ! :-D although still does not support nested values

Comment: But there is one question. If two or more curly braces appear with normal letters separated, such as "A,B,{C,D,{E,F}},G,{H,I},J", this regex will get
A
B
{C,D,{E,F}},G,{H,I}
J
Maybe this is not what you want.

Comment: Well I have to admit I am a little confused with this one... I kinda think I better keep the implementation without the regex in order to be easier to read and maintain :-(

Answer (score 2):

A regex that supports nesting would look as follows:

```
my @items;
push @items, $1 while
   /
      (?: ^ | \G , )
      (
         (?: [^,{}]+
         |   (
                \{
                   (?: [^{}]
                   |   (?2)
                   )*
                \}
             )
         |   # Empty
         )
      )
   /xg;
```

```
$ perl -E'$_ = shift; ... say for @items;' 'A,B,{C,D,{E,F}},G'
A
B
{C,D,{E,F}}
G
```

Assumes valid input since it can't extract and validate at the same time. (Well, not without making things really messy.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = "A,B,{C,D,E},F";
while ($a =~ s/(\{[\{\}\w,]+\}|\w)//) {
    push (@res, $1);
}
print "\@res: @res\n"
```

Result:

```
@res: A B {C,D,E} F
```

Explanation : we try to match either the protected block `\{[\{\}\w,]+\}` or just a single character `\w` successively in a loop, deleting it from the original string if there is a match. Every time there is a match, we store it (meaning the `$1`) in the array, et voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex in bash:

```
chronos@localhost / $ echo "A,B,{C,D,E},F" | grep -oE "(\{[^\}]*\}|[A-Z])"
A
B
{C,D,E}
F
```

Comment: I think he wants it in `perl` ?

Comment: It should work in perl. It is pretty much the same as the one you posted.

Comment: I agree, except that I would use `\w` instead of `[A-Z]` because it's more general. :-)

Comment: Yep, that works and it's compatible with perl regex, but it does not work with nested `{}`

Comment: Because I did not mention the nested requirement at the 1st place ;-)

Comment: @Christophe, But you did chance the question. Please accept an answer that actually answers the question as it stands. You should have asked two different questions if that's not what you wanted. Besides, even if the question hadn't been changed, nesting seems like an important point to bring up in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. Use the regex to match and extract the token.

```
/(\{.*?\}|(?<=,|^).*?(?=,|$))/
```

I have not tested this code in Perl.

There is an assumption about on how the regex engine works here (I assume that it will try to match the first part `\{.*?\}` before the second part). I also assume that there are no nested curly bracket, and badly paired curly brackets.

Comment: looks a bit complicated :-) And Y U NO test it ? :-)

Comment: @BaL: Only tested the regex on rubular. I don't know Perl enough to write a working test for it. It is a bit complicated because I assume A, B, C, etc. represents some real text, rather than single character.

Answer (score -2):

```
$s = "A,B,{C,D,E},F";
@t = split /,(?=.*{)|,(?!.*})/, $s;
```

Comment: Then why is his answer accepted rather than mine ? :D Plus he doesn't give any explanation :-(